# Live action Australian/New Zealand superhero kids show from mid-2000s

Tags: story-identification, super-hero

I was just wondering if anyone could help me figure out the name/synopsis of this kids show.

What I remember of it:
The show was live action, and about 2 kids (a boy and a girl) who discover the base of a retired/dead superhero, who is now stored in a computer and displayed as floating head on the screen (similar to Zordon from Power Rangers).

The base, as well as the gadgets/costumes had a 1940's style tech design, I think the superhero's gimmick had something to do with a manta ray?

The main villain of the show is the young granddaughter to the arch-nemesis of the old hero, who is now in a wheelchair and elderly.

The show was originally from either Australia or New Zealand, and was shown in the mid 2000s (perhaps 2005?), aired on the BBC, during their CBBC time slot.

Answer (score 10):

The show is [Legacy of the Silver Shadow](http://www.actf.com.au/sales-program/legacy-of-the-silver-shadow).

> Josh, Alex, Campbell and Gretel are thrown together when they discover the underground headquarters of the Silver Shadow, a long-forgotten dead superhero.  Although defeated in the 1950s by his arch enemy, the Crab, the Silver Shadow lives on as a digital recording in an old computer.

Comment: thankyou so much, finalily i know the name of the show from my childhood, thankyou =),

Comment: @Joe, no worries. As soon as I saw your post I knew *exactly what you meant*. If this is the correct answer though, don't forget you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark.